# Showing that a convex set $A$ is closed if and only if $A \cap \mathcal{l}$ is closed for every line $\mathcal{l} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, convex-analysis

We assume a convex set $A$ and a line segment $\mathcal{l} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. We have to show that $A$ is closed if and only if its intersection with any given line is a closed set.

$(\implies) $ If $A$ is closed then that means its complement is an open set. Therefore we can assume that $x \in A^{c}$ open set. Can we say that the intersection of an open set with a line segment is an open set? As such to deduce that its complement is closed?

$(\impliedby)$ No idea sadly.

Comment: The first implication is easy, as any line is a closed set. So its intersection with a closed set is closed.

Comment: To get $A\cap \ell$ via the complement, you'd want to do $A^c\cup \ell^c$, and $\ell^c$ is open.

Comment: @Dave are you answering the $\implies$ part or the $\impliedby$ part?

Comment: My comment is in response to your $\implies$ arrow. You're trying to show that $(A\cap \ell)^c$ is open, but $(A\cap \ell)^c=A^c\cup \ell^c$.

Comment: What is $l$? A line segment of finite length (open, half-open, closed)? Or a full  line?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints for "$\Leftarrow$":

- It is sufficient to consider the case that $A$ has nonempty interior.
- For $x \in \partial A$ and $y \in \operatorname{int}(A)$, all points on the open segment between $x$ and $y$ belong to the interior $\operatorname{int}(A)$.

Comment: If all points on the open segment belong to the interior, then proof is over?

Comment: Then it remains to use the assumption.

Comment: Are you answering for the $\implies$ part or the $\impliedby$ part? Also, can you make the slightest effort to write that in your "answer"?

Comment: My answer gives some hints for "$\Leftarrow$".

Comment: I still cannot understand your hint. Would you mind giving maybe a whole answer or a more complete inquiry.